# Eclipse built-in maven support vs M2Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

Has Eclipse 3.7.2 built-in Maven support? How does it differ from m2eclipse?

[image: mvn_builtin]

[image: m2e]

**@EDIT**

`m2e` basic version is bundled with Eclipse 3.7 Java (not yet with Java EE). For the full version one has to install `m2e` from either its update site or the Marketplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List of Indigo (Eclipse 3.7) projects: http://www.eclipse.org/indigo/projects.php

Includes Maven support [new]: http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/

As you can guess by the name it is just m2e bundled with the release (and upped the version number from the external source).

Comment: Thanks. m2e should be the eclipse bundled version of m2eclipse from http://www.sonatype.org/m2eclipse/

Answer (score 1):

You can install maven eclipse from here - http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/

Note: Sonatype contributed m2e plugin to eclipse. You can read about it here  http://www.sonatype.com/people/2011/06/where-is-m2eclipse/